# How to pass array of arrays through jQuery ajax

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, json

I have a PHP array which is created in the following way:

```
$treearr = array(
  array("root","search","Search",false,"xpLens.gif"),
  array("root","hometab","Home Tab",false,"home.gif"),
  array("root","stafftab","Staff Tab",false,"person.gif"),
  array ("stafftab","newstaff","New Staff",false,"newperson.gif"));
```

(it generates a tree view control)

How do I convert this array into a javascript array which I can pass into a jQuery ajax call?

I've looked at many similar questions but nobody seems to have an array in this same format.  I've tried all kinds of combinations of json_decode, json_encode, JSON.stringify(), JSON.parse(),$.parseJSON, and nothing works.

Comment: `echo json_encode($treearr)` should work just fine ?

Comment: Sorry, yes of course.  It's PHP.  I'll update my question.

Comment: Using echo json_encode gives me this :  "root,search,Search,false,xpLens.gif,root,hometab,Home Tab,false,home.gif,root,stafftab,Staff Tab,false,person.gif,stafftab,newstaff,New Staff,false,newperson.gif".  How do I pass this into an ajax call?

Comment: You just echo it, and get in the success callback in the ajax call

Answer (score 1):

In your php file

```
 $treearr = array(
    array("root","search","Search",false,"xpLens.gif"),
    array("root","hometab","Home Tab",false,"home.gif"),
    array("root","stafftab","Staff Tab",false,"person.gif"),
    array ("stafftab","newstaff","New Staff",false,"newperson.gif"));

header('Content-Type: application/json');
echo json_encode($treearr);
```

and in your js file

```
        $.ajax({
    url: '/path/to/file',
    type: 'GET',
    dataType: 'json',

})
.done(function(data) {
    console.log(data);
})
.fail(function() {
    console.log("error");
})
.always(function() {
    console.log("complete");
});
```